# awk + How do I find duplicates in a column?

Tags: awk

How do I find duplicates in a column?

```
$ head countries_lat_long_int_code3.csv | cat -n
     1  country,latitude,longitude,name,code
     2  AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
     3  AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
     4  AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
     5  AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
     6  AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
     7  AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
     8  AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,374
     9  AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,599
    10  AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,244
```

For instance this has duplicates in the 5th column.

```
     5  AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
     6  AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
```

How do I view all the others in this file?

I know I can do this:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{print $5}' countries_lat_long_int_code3.csv | sort
```

And I can eyeball and see if there is any duplicates, but is there a better way?

Or I can do this:
Find out how may are there completely

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print $5}' countries_lat_long_int_code3.csv | sort | wc -l
210
```

Find out how many unique values are there

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print $5}' countries_lat_long_int_code3.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
183
```

Therefore there are at most 27 (210-183) duplicates.

**EDIT1**

My desired output would be something as follows, basically all the columns but just showing the rows that are duplicates:

```
 5  AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
 6  AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
```

Comment: what about `awk -F, 'NR>1{print $5}' countries_lat_long_int_code3.csv | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 *'` ?  Taht will group all the duplicate lines using uniq -c and remove all the ones that appear once.

Comment: What is your desired output.  Count of duplicate codes, duplicate records, unique codes?

Comment: are you only care of the 5th field or any others?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will give you the duplicated codes

```
awk -F, 'a[$5]++{print $5}'
```

if you're only interested in count of duplicate codes

```
awk -F, 'a[$5]++{count++} END{print count}'
```

To print duplicated rows try this

```
awk -F, '$5 in a{print a[$5]; print} {a[$5]=$0}'
```

This will print the whole row with duplicates found in col $5:

```
awk -F, 'a[$5]++{print $0}'
```

Comment: Your last one works OK when there's just one repeat.  However, if there's another line with `$5 == 1`, then it prints the Anguilla line a second time.  You can work around that easily enough.  I used a slightly verbose: `awk -F, '{if (count[$5] > 1) print $0; else if (count[$5] == 1) { print save[$5]; print $0; } else save[$5] = $0; count[$5]++; }'`. The count array records how many times $5 has been seen before. If it's more than once, just print the new record; if it's only once, print the saved (first) record and the new record; otherwise, this is new so save $0. Increment the count anyway.

Comment: what does `a` represent in `a[$5]`?

Comment: it's the name of the array that holds `$5` as keys, the value is incremented each time so overall this behaves like the python `Counter` object in this context.

Comment: When I try to run this, it's just stuck (my file contains 4 million rows ~500 Mb)

Comment: It should not stuck, it should start printing with the first duplicate record.  Your file size should not matter for the script to start printing.  Perhaps you're doing something else?

Comment: I do `awk -F ';' 'a[$`1]++{print $1}'` as I have a `;` for a separator.

Comment: `$1` there shouldn't a space there.

Comment: also try with `head -100 file | awk ... ` to test the script with the first few records.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your comment is useful. I suggest you to edit the post with your comments and code, or replay the question as new answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the less memory aggressive i can guess:

```
$ cat infile
country,latitude,longitude,name,code
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,374
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,599
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,355

$ awk -F\, '$NF in a{if (a[$NF]!=0){print a[$NF];a[$NF]=0}print;next}{a[$NF]=$0}' infile
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,355
```

NOTE:  I have included another duplicate for testing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to print out a unique value that repeat over the same file just add at the end of the awk:

awk ... ... | sort | uniq -u

That will print the unique values only on alphabetic order

Comment: That is not the question and the question already has this solution